# pegar a data no evento select do fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Gostaria de saber como pegar o valor da `data` ao fazer o *select* de um dia no fullcalendar

```
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        alert('Valor da data: ' + start);
 }
```

Tenho feito assim mas não funcionar

Answer (score 3):

Lendo a documentação eles sugerem usar o [.formatRange()](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/formatRange/), e podes usar o mesmo dia no inicio e fim desse range/intervalo. Repara também que uso maiúsculas no formato da data: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Assim:

```
select: function (start, end, allDay) {
    start = $.fullCalendar.formatRange(start, start, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    alert('Valor da data: ' + start);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1y8a6rce/

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: @Expedito ótimo! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui assim :

```
selectable: true,
      select: function (start) {
        console.log(start.startStr);
        alert('Valor da data: ' + start.startStr);
      }
```